# keycloak gatekeeper doesn't block any request

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper, louketo-proxy

I am trying using keycloak + keycloak-gatekeeper for authorization in a personal api: `api.mydomain.com`. so far i have done:

1. Created a realm `MY-REALM` in keycloak, the URL for keycloak is https://auth.mydomain.com
2. Created a `confidential client` in the same realm with `Authorization Enabled` **ON** and `Valid redirect URIS`: https://api.mydomain.com/*
3. Created a user
4. Inside my server https://api.mydomain.com points to 127.0.0.1:5000
5. 127.0.0.1:5001 is the "real API"
6. Configured keycloak-gatekeeper with this config.yaml:

```
client-id: <MY-API-CLIENT-ID>
client-secret: <SECRET>
discovery-url: https://auth.mydomain.com/auth/realms/<MY-REALM>
enable-default-deny: true
listen: 127.0.0.1:5000
upstream-url: http://127.0.0.1:5001
verbose: true
enable-logging: true
enable-security-filter: true
enable-json-logging: true
```

Right now if i access in a browser https://api.mydomain.com i am redirected to https://auth.mydomain.com asking for an user and password. i supply the user created in the point 3 and as expected redirected again to https://api.mydomain.com. so far so good.

The problem lies in the configuration of the Authorization part:
In keycloak -> `Clients` -> `<MY-API-CLIENT-ID>` -> `Authorization` -> `Resources` i edit the default policy to **Deny** every request in the `resource` **/*** but i can access every resource (URL) in https://api.mydomain.com just as before.

I have tried:

1. Restrict by realm role (only admins can access to a particular resource).
2. Restrict by scope.
3. Negate the logic in the policy.
4. Restrict by client role.
5. Pray.
6. Cry.

Of course i have tried every combination of the above in the `Evaluate` Tab on keycloak and effectively here the simulated policy show **DENY**.

So what i am doing wrong? By the way, after every request this is the log from keycloak-gatekeeper:

```
{"level":"debug","ts":1554936731.4022436,"caller":"keycloak-gatekeeper/middleware.go:337","msg":"access permitted to resource","access":"permitted","email":"testmail@mail.com","expires":201.59779997,"resource":"/*"}
```

Any ideas will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: If you know another free OpenidConnect/Identity and Access Management/Authorization server (or a combination of systems with the same purpose) that you can recommend that would be also super cool.

Comment: The enforcement of Keycloak authorizations in Gatekeeper has been requested here : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatekeeper doesn't use `Keycloak -> Clients -> <MY-API-CLIENT-ID> -> Authorization -> Resources`.

It has own configuration of resources, e.g.:

```
resources:
- uri: /admin/*
  methods:
  - GET
  roles:
  - openvpn:vpn-user
  - openvpn:commons-prod-vpn
```

Doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#configuration-options

Comment: OMG I have lost _days_ thinking that i misconfigured something... So... you know how i can use keycloak authorization services if my api is not writen in java and there is no `client adapter` for my language?... I'm screwed ?

Comment: Is there no way to get this to respect the role restrictions in keycloak itself, instead of having to specify it again in the manifest?

Comment: @Christian you can use louketo-proxy, which is a proxy you'll have in front of front/backends, there you can apply the configuration on this answer. As JWT is seld-contained, the louketo-proxy itself can authorize the app behind it, with no need to connect to keycloak server.

Comment: @bck `louketo-proxy` = `Gatekeeper` (that is former name). louketo-proxy needs connection to the Keycloak server - it is using OIDC discovery URL, to get more details about IDP (for example auth URL, realm keys, ...)